# Scrolling too fast through photos

Tags: windows-7, scrolling

When I'm searching through photos the computer scrolls so fast I can't see them. I can get it to go slower by constantly tapping the touch pad and then it suddenly scrolls super fast again. How do I turn off the super fast scrolling?

Comment: What brand of laptop is it (I assume it's a laptop based on the touchpad)?  What software are you using to browse the photos?  Is the speed directly related to the touchpad action or are you describing a situation where the computer lags because it gets busy and then catches up on a collection of previous scrolls?  Have you tried adjusting the speed in the touchpad/mouse settings?  Is the computer generally fast enough or does it routinely hang/lag?  Do you have the same issue browsing the file list in Windows Explorer?

Answer (score 1):

1) Use Windows Explorer to view the photos as thumbnails; the size of the thumbnail image may be changed: http://www.technipages.com/windows-change-image-thumbnail-size
2) Try the free IrfanView (http://www.irfanview.com/) which has adjustable parameters for viewing files, including a slideshow mode with configurable interval.

Comment: Irfanview is great if you have to do pretty much anything involving images short of the kind of complex image manipulation that requires Photoshop.